# Smartface Emulator to device always failed when Installing Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, smartface.io

I'm having a problem when trying to do the smartface android emulation directly using USB to device. It's always stuck, without any error message, in this state:

> Checking Android SDK Configuration.
>   Searching Devices...
>   Device found: GT-N7100.
>   Generating Exporting Packages for Android profile:"Default".
>       Pages, JavaScripts files are preparing.
>       Project resources are preparing.
>       Datasets are preparing.
>       Installation packages are creating.
>   **Installing Emulator...**

It stucks in 'Installing Emulator'. Nothing installed on my Galaxy Note 2 device. Didn't try yet with other device. What could be the problem? Any logs to check?
USB debugging enabled, device detected by ADB...

Comment: Can you try with new releae of Smartface app studio? You can download from the link : https://account.smartface.io/Account/Register/ . If you are trying with this release, and facing the same problem again, then can you please check the available free space of your device?

Comment: I was just installed smartface when having the problem. The release is 4.4.0, built 1508042142. I still have around 2.5 GB of free space in my device storage.

Comment: Can you share information about your computer(for example if you are using windows what is the edition, operating system is 32 or 64 bits). And also can you please tell which device do you use, what is its Android version?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, kitkat 4.4.2. It was my USB cable... I was using generic cable... somehow maybe the generic cable can't connect normally to my laptop USB port. Or maybe my USB port is not working normally. Now using original cable from the device, and it works... :) thank you for your support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's solved. The problem is with the USB cable and/or my USB port at my laptop. I was using generic USB cables when having the problem.
I noticed that copying file using the USB cable also stuck.

So, I try the original cable from the manufacturer, and try also other original cable from other manufacturer brand. It was success... Now the emulator runs perfectly to my device.

Thank you all for the supports..